# Is a for loop with exponential time complexity O(c^n) possible?

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, big-o

Is it possible to get exponential time complexity e.g. O(2<sup>n</sup>) or O(3<sup>n</sup>) in JavaScript by using **just** `for` loops?

[Here](https://www.quora.com/Are-algorithms-with-a-time-complexity-of-k-n-only-implemented-recursively/answer/Kevin-Latimer-4?ch=10&oid=41846597&share=b20cd6ab&target_type=answer) someone posted such solution:

```
function my_sum(n) { 
    long sum = 0; 
    for (int i=0; i < (1L << n); i++) { 
        sum += i * (i - 1); 
    } 
    return sum; 
}
```

I don't understand what it does though. Can someone explain what the example does? How can I do the same in JavaScript?

Comment: Please, remove tags `c` and `c++` from your question, since only Javascript is involved. BTW, BigO and time complexity are related to algorithms, not typically programming languages. That means that you want first to find an algorithm with that complexity, and *then* you may implement it in any language you want.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 2ⁿ; ++i)` is indeed in `O(2ⁿ)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `(1L << n)` is a binary shift. You're shifting bits to the left. That way, that `1L` (1, long), is converted from the binary `0001` (1) to `0010` (2), then `0100` (4)... Apply that shift N times, and you're making `2^N` (`Math.pow(2, n)` in JS).

The readable way in JS, would be to write:

```js
function mySum(n) {
    let sum = 0; 
    for (let i=0; i < Math.pow(2, n); i++) { 
        sum += i * (i - 1); 
    } 
    return sum; 
}
```